# Star of David theorem in Pascal's pyramid

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Few days ago I found out the [Star of David theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_David_theorem). Is there an analogue in [Pascal's pyramid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_pyramid)? I tried to do some calculations on the base that the star of David is basically two equilateral triangles superimposed, so I tried to do the same with two regular thetraedron, but didn't found the same relation.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun thanks for pointing that out. I edited adding my (failed) trial

Comment: What do you consider to be the 3D analogue of a star of David? For instance, which are the neighbours of the point $\binom{n}{i,j,k}$? I'm not sure if the geometry works out as nicely on the 3D lattice.

Comment: @ChrisLewis I tried with a stellated octahedron https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellated_octahedron

Answer (score 3):

There are two versions of the star of David theorem in two dimensions; one version equates the gcd's of two surrounding triangles, the other version equates the products of the triangles. I found a generalization of the product version to three dimensions. For my generalization, there are three quadrilaterals surrounding each entry in Pascal's pyramid, and the products of these three quadrilaterals are equal.

**Proposition:** For any $i,j,k,n\ge 0$ such that $n=i+j+k$,
$$
\binom{n}{i+1,j-1,k}\times \binom{n}{i-1,j+1,k}\times \binom{n+1}{i,j,k+1}\times \binom{n-1}{i,j,k-1}=\\
\binom{n}{i+1,j,k-1}\times \binom{n}{i-1,j,k+1}\times \binom{n+1}{i,j+1,k}\times \binom{n-1}{i,j-1,k}=\\
\binom{n}{i,j+1,k-1}\times \binom{n}{i,j-1,k+1}\times \binom{n+1}{i+1,j,k}\times \binom{n-1}{i-1,j,k}.\;\;\;
$$

*Proof:* Convert all multinomials to factorials, and notice that all three parts of the equation have identical numerators and denominators, up to a reordering of the factors. $\square$

However, the gcd version does not generalize in this same fashion. In the case where $(i,j,k)=(2,1,1)$, we have
$$
\gcd\left(\binom{4}{1,2,1},\binom{4}{3,0,1},\binom{3}{2,1,0},\binom{5}{2,1,2}\right)=1\neq\\
\gcd\left(\binom{4}{2,2,0},\binom{4}{2,0,2},\binom{3}{1,1,1},\binom{5}{3,1,1}\right)=2\;\;\;\;
$$